# Flexbox Box model vs CSS frameworks for Apache Cordova mobile apps

Tags: css, cordova, flexbox, css-frameworks

I'm planning to develop a cross-platform mobile application for Android, iOS and Windows Phone for teaching languages using Apache Cordova. The app should work on and offline.

My question is how should I develop the CSS? I have recently learned about the CSS3 Flexbox Box model which seems pretty interesting. Is that enough for my purpose or do you recommend some other CSS frameworks like Bootstrap? If so, which framework and why?

Please note that I'm not interested in frameworks that are not free for commercial use.

Comment: Ali, your question is not only a beginners question, it has misconceptions.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650: considering that my question is very specific I don't think it's so bad that I don't know the basics of this field.

Comment: I'm going to repeat - your question has misconceptions. First of all Flexbox is but one corner of the CSS world, as such a framework may use either, both, or none. So, there is no reason to make that the center of a question. Next, CSS works across all platforms, but each behaves differently. On that the ALL Work online and offline. In summation, you are really asking about Bootstrap, which is one of a dozen frameworks available. You are asking a Lazy-person question, so you should right expect the worst answers. enjoy your day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) would be a more than acceptable option here, it allows you to then use any JavaScript frameworks that you like to build the rest of your application.  It has a large developer community and easy to override CSS should you want to.  For example, I've built Cordova applications using Bootstrap with JQuery and Handlebars as a templating engine, but you could use React JS, Angular etc if you wanted to.

If you want something that is more tied to a specific JS framework, consider the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/).  I've also successfully completed Cordova projects with this, it's very fast and well supported but does tie you to Angular JS at this point (although this may not be the case in future).

[JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) would also give you a big CSS / UI elements headstart without tying you to a specific JavaScript framework, but isn't as actively maintained these days.

The [Dojo Toolkit](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/mobile/flickrview/part1/index.html) could be a consideration too.

[Sencha Touch](https://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) gives you a UI framework along with a MVC model and data store / management capabilities, but has a high learning curve.

Comment: If you want to see how a Bootstrap with (optional) Handlebars and JQuery Cordova 5 app looks try https://github.com/simonprickett/bartcordova

Comment: your answer was so helpful. I also learned from your Github code.